# Choosing VPS specs

Tags: linux, vps

i'm planning to sign up for a VPS account. On the VPS i'm planning to host ~5 SVN repos, a few php-based lowtraffic websites, a gameserver (MineCraft) and probably some other small apps.

The SVN repos will only be updates once or twice a day so they wont take much diskspace or traffic.

The websites can be quite rich of images, but has a low ammount of visitors.

I don't know wery much about the MineCraft server. But as we will be ~5 players, i don't think it will take much traffic or memory.

Now to my question. What specifications do i need? Is 128mb RAM enough? How much traffic/month do i need?

Answer (score 1):

According to internet resources you should at least have 512 MB of RAM only for a minecraft server. Most recommendations I read suggest even more.

The SVN repos really shouldn't be the problem - I think the only thing to worry about svn would be the diskspace and bandwidth.

128MB RAM are definitively, absolutely, really not enough. There is no need to talk further about the webserver. Even for a small webserver it would be advised to use more RAM.

I don't want to advertise here for any special provider. But we talked about this subject in the chat and German providers seem to have pretty competitive prices i.e. at [server4you.com/vserver](http://www.server4you.com/vserver/)

Comment: Just for info: server4you runs OpenVZ

Answer (score 1):

You can run a couple low-usage sites (several thousand pages a day) on a 128MB VPS no problem. I'm doing it now. If your really good you could use a [64MB](http://www.lowendbox.com/blog/bootstraping-low-end-vps-with-pre-built-scripts/) [VPS](http://www.lowendbox.com/blog/wordpress-cheap-vps-lowendscript/).  However, the game server is probably what will get you.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least 512MB RAM and 50GB of bandwidth. I recommend you to choose XEN virtualization instead of OpenVZ.

Comment: Where di d you get the 50GB bandwidth from?

Comment: SVN repos and websites